# Can't get ActiveRecord::Store to work in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Has ActiveRecord::Store changed in later versions of 3.2?  I can't find out a lot about it in my searches. Some think it great, others have 
opinions. There are a few early 3.2 release blog entries out there, most just using the console to update the attributes in a ActiveRecord::Store. There are 
a few 
*examples/tutorials* using it with a form. Most use the store attributes just like a column, but I can't get it to work. Also can't get some of the console examples to work.

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
  AD_ATTR = [:job_area, :end_date, :ad_url, :instructions, :other]
  store :ad, :assessors => AD_ATTR
  attr_accessible *AD_ATTR, :date, :enterable, :est_candidates, :name, :status, :program_id, :sequence
end

# I've also tried it without the * and defining each accessor
```

Some tutorials show using the store from the console using object dot notation. Mine does not work. Using it as a hash works fine.

```
1.9.2-p136 :752 > s = Stage.find(1)
 => #<Stage id: 1, ... , ad: {}, sequence: 1> 
1.9.2-p136 :753 > s.ad
 => {} 
1.9.2-p136 :754 > s.other
NoMethodError: undefined method `other' for #<Stage:0x00000103de4528>

1.9.2-p136 :755 > s.ad[:other]
 => nil 

1.9.2-p136 :756 > s.other = "stuff"
NoMethodError: undefined method `other=' for #<Stage:0x00000103de4528>

1.9.2-p136 :757 > s.ad[:other] = "stuff"
 => "stuff" 
1.9.2-p136 :758 > a.other
NoMethodError: undefined method `other' for #<Take::Assessment:0x000001038ba778>
```

Then in a form, if I try:

```
<tr class="field">
  <th><%= f.label :other %></th>
  <td><%= f.text_field :other %></td>
</tr>
```

I'll get:

```
undefined method 'other' for #<Stage:0x0000010396a650>
```

I'm sure I can hack around it, or just use JSON like I have in a few other places. This seemed to be a nice fit since only a small number of the Stage records have need for the ad attributes.

EDIT

Could not help myself from hacking. I got it to work, but, according to the stuff I can find, it should work as just a model attribute.

In the form, I used fields_form:

```
<%= fields_for :ad_fields do |a| %>
  <tr class="field">
    <th><%= a.label :other %></th>
    <td><%= a.text_field :other, :value => @stage.ad[:other] %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="field">
    <th><%= a.label :job_area %></th>
    <td><%= a.text_field :job_area, :value => @stage.ad[:job_area] %></td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
```

In the controller for update, I populated the store.

```
def update
  @stage = Stage.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if params[:ad_fields]
      params[:ad_fields].each do |key,value|
        @stage.ad[key.to_sym] = value
      end
    end
    if @stage.update_attributes(params[:stage])
    ...
  end
```

Using this method you can also put in other objects into the value, which someone already has a gem store_field. My hack at 
least will let me evaluate using ActiveRecord::Store

Steve

Comment: did you found a better solution?

Comment: I gave up on ::Store. I ended up just using serialize :data, JSON if I wanted to serialize a hash in a column (:data in this case), in a model.